# Mongoose MongoDB in Node.js - Saving datetime in local timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using Mongoose in NodeJS project. I have this schema:

```
let InventorySchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    tradable: {
        type: Date,
        default: () => {
            return new Date().getTime()
        }
    }
}, {
    versionKey: false
});
```

I live in Prague (GMT+01:00). When I insert "line" into my document, `tradable` is set automatically (because of default) to datetime without GMT. For example time now is in my city 16:51 but into database its saved as 15:51

How to save correct datetime? NodeJS `Date` giving me correct datetime when it is called normally.

EDIT: Using `Date.now` not helping! Same output

Answer (score 0):

Use [getTimezoneOffset](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getTimezoneOffset)() It will provide you the offset :

```
var date = new Date(); //ex 2019-01-18T16:26:44.982Z
var offset = - date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60; //in your case 1
```

And you add the offset to your date.